# Как реализовать анимацию появления кривых линий?

Tags: вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, js-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При загрузке страницы , должны появляться линии по направлению точки(левые направо , правые налево), в конце анимации ,на каждой появляется точка.

Comment: для начала надо их нарисовать .. желательно в векторном формате и на выходе получится svg с path вот как достигнете этого результата - пишите сюда .. сама анимашка делается на smil - почитайте что это такое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кривые линии, как комментировал **@Monkey Mutant**, нарисованы в векторном редакторе.
Анимация этих линий реализована командой анимации SMIL

```
    <animate id="an_p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="4s" 
      values="793;0" fill="freeze" />
```

Появление цветных точек:

```
<set id="c1" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p1.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/>
```

Эта анимация начнётся, когда закончится анимация рисования соответствующей линии
`begin="an_p1.end"`

Откройте сниппет на полный размер

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="800" height="200" viewBox="0 0 800 200"   >  
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#151515" />
  
   <path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="793" stroke-dashoffset="793" d="M778.5 38.6S730.3 19.1 705 20c-25.7 1-47.5 24.4-73.3 24.5-26.1 0-48.3-25-74.3-24.5-28.3.7-51 29.9-79.3 30.4-31 .5-57-31.3-88-30.4-23.6.8-41.8 27.1-65.5 27.4-26.2.4-47.2-29.5-73.4-28.3-21.4 1-36.2 28.7-57.7 28.3-22.9-.3-38-29-60.6-32.2-30.3-4.4-90 18.5-90 18.5">
     <animate id="an_p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="793;0" fill="freeze" />
   </path> 
    <circle fill="cyan" opacity="0" cx="43" cy="34.2" rx="3.9" r="4" >
       <set id="c1" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p1.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </circle>   
 
 <path id="p2" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="763" stroke-dashoffset="763"  d="M39.1 96.3S175 56.4 244.5 58.2c54.6 1.4 104.8 40.3 159.4 38.1 57.2-2.2 106.1-51 163.3-52.8 71.6-2.3 208.4 52.8 208.4 52.8" >
       <animate id="an_p2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" dur="4s" values="763;0" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
  <circle opacity="0" fill="yellowgreen" cx="776.5" cy="95.8"  r="4" >
   <set id="c2" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p2.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
   </circle>
     
      
      <path id="p3" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="828" stroke-dashoffset="828" d="M38.1 131.5s116.8 51.3 174.1 36.2c27.7-7.3 37-49.2 64.6-56.7 83-22.5 171 74.1 253.3 48.9 37.4-11.5 45-74.1 83.1-83.1 56.2-13.3 164.3 54.7 164.3 54.7" >
           <animate id="an_p3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="2s" dur="4s" values="828;0" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
    <circle opacity="0" fill="orange" cx="776.5" cy="131.1"  r="4" >
      <set id="c3" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p3.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
   </circle>    
      </svg>
```

***Вариант запуска анимации после какого-нибудь события, например щелчка по холсту SVG***

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="800" height="200" viewBox="0 0 800 200"   >  
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#151515" />
  
   <path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="793" stroke-dashoffset="793" d="M778.5 38.6S730.3 19.1 705 20c-25.7 1-47.5 24.4-73.3 24.5-26.1 0-48.3-25-74.3-24.5-28.3.7-51 29.9-79.3 30.4-31 .5-57-31.3-88-30.4-23.6.8-41.8 27.1-65.5 27.4-26.2.4-47.2-29.5-73.4-28.3-21.4 1-36.2 28.7-57.7 28.3-22.9-.3-38-29-60.6-32.2-30.3-4.4-90 18.5-90 18.5">
     <animate id="an_p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="793;0" fill="freeze" />
   </path> 
    <circle fill="cyan" opacity="0" cx="43" cy="34.2" rx="3.9" r="4" >
       <set id="c1" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p1.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </circle>   
 
 <path id="p2" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="763" stroke-dashoffset="763"  d="M39.1 96.3S175 56.4 244.5 58.2c54.6 1.4 104.8 40.3 159.4 38.1 57.2-2.2 106.1-51 163.3-52.8 71.6-2.3 208.4 52.8 208.4 52.8" >
       <animate id="an_p2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click+1s" dur="4s" values="763;0" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
  <circle opacity="0" fill="yellowgreen" cx="776.5" cy="95.8"  r="4" >
   <set id="c2" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p2.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
   </circle>
     
      
      <path id="p3" fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="828" stroke-dashoffset="828" d="M38.1 131.5s116.8 51.3 174.1 36.2c27.7-7.3 37-49.2 64.6-56.7 83-22.5 171 74.1 253.3 48.9 37.4-11.5 45-74.1 83.1-83.1 56.2-13.3 164.3 54.7 164.3 54.7" >
           <animate id="an_p3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click+2s" dur="4s" values="828;0" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
    <circle opacity="0" fill="orange" cx="776.5" cy="131.1"  r="4" >
      <set id="c3" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_p3.end" to="1" fill="freeze"/> 
   </circle>    
      </svg>
```

Comment: большое спасибо Александр

Comment: @Profet Всегда готов помочь